# Error al devolver datos

Tags: javascript

Necesito que me devuelva el valor que tengo comentado cuando llamo a la función likes, me devuelve siempre el ultimo return y no se por que.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que intentas hacer realmente es algo así:

```js
function likes(numero) {
  const stringNumero = numero.toString();
  if (stringNumero.length<4) return stringNumero;
  if (stringNumero.length<7) return `${stringNumero.substr(0, stringNumero.length-3)} K`;
  return `${stringNumero.substr(0, stringNumero.length-6)} M`;
}

console.log(likes(983));
console.log(likes(1_900));
console.log(likes(54_000));
console.log(likes(120_800));
console.log(likes(25_222_444));
```

Aunque no veo ninguna necesidad de tratar el número como texto. La función se puede simplificar a lo siguiente:

```js
function likes(numero) {
  if (numero<1000) return `${Math.floor(numero)}`;
  if (numero<1000000) return `${Math.floor(numero/1000)} K`;
  return `${Math.floor(numero/1000000)} M`;
}

console.log(likes(983));
console.log(likes(1_900));
console.log(likes(54_000));
console.log(likes(120_800));
console.log(likes(25_222_444));
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes comparar el **total de caracteres** en vez de una cadena de caracteres, también te recomiendo evitar el uso de var, en vez utiliza let

```js
function likes(numero) {
  let resultado = `${numero}`;
  const stringNumero = numero.toString();
  const caracteres = stringNumero.length;

  if (caracteres >= 4 && caracteres <= 6) {
    resultado += ' K';
  } else if (caracteres >= 7) {
    resultado += ' M';
  }

  return resultado;
}

console.log(likes(983));
console.log(likes(1_900));
console.log(likes(54_000));
console.log(likes(120_800));
console.log(likes(25_222_444));
```